# Activerecord query returning doubles while using uniq

Tags: sql, activerecord

I am running the following query with the goal of returning a unique set of `customer` objects:

```
Customer.joins(:projects).select('customers.*, projects.finish_date').where("projects.closed = false").uniq
```

However, this code will generate duplicates if a customer has more than one project active (e.g. closed = true). If I remove the `projects.finish_date` from the `select` clause this query works as intended. However, I need this to be in there to be able to sort on that column.

**How can I make this query return a unique set of customers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make this query return a unique set of customers?

This doesn't completely make sense, and probably isn't what you want.

The problem is that you're joining against the `projects` table, at which point there  may be several rows for the same customer with different project `finish_date`s. These rows **are** unique and will be returned as multiple unique `Customer` objects, each with different a `finish_date`.

If you only want one of these, how is Rails to determine which one? Wouldn't it be a problem if you only had one customer object with one `finish_date` returned if there are really 10 projects for that customer, each with a different `finish_date`?

Instead, you probably want something like this:

```
customers = Customer.joins(:projects).select('customers.*, projects.finish_date').where("projects.closed = false").uniq

customers.group_by(&:id)
```

This groups all of your same customers together.

OR, you might want:

```
projects = Project.where(closed: false).includes(:user)
users = projects.map(&:user).uniq
```

In either case, you're producing a unique set of users from the superset of all user-project joins.

---

RE Your comments:

If you want to get a list of customers with their *most recent* associated project, you could use a sub query in your `where`:

```
select customers.*, projects.finish_date from customers
  inner join projects on projects.customer_id = customers.id
  where projects.id = (
    select id from projects
      where customer.id = project.customer_id
        and closed = false
      order by finish_date desc
      limit 1
  )
```

You can express this using ActiveRecord by embedding the sub-query in a `where`:

```
Customer.joins(:projects)
  .select('customers.*, projects.finish_date as finish_date')
  .where('select id from projects where customer.id = project.customer_id and closed = false order by finish_date desc limit 1')
```

I have no idea how this will perform for you, but I suspect poorly.

I would *always* stick to a simple `includes` and in-Ruby filter before attempting to optimize with SQL.

Comment: You're probably right in that I am doing something silly. What I want is a set of customers that have active projects. I can get these by using `Customer.joins(:projects).where('project.closed = false').uniq` that works fine. However, I also want to be able to sort those customers on their most recent project. I see the problem though, rails not knowing which project to use for that sort (answer: the most recent one)..

Comment: @ErwinM you could do this with a sub-query, so long as you have some criteria by which to choose exactly one project per customer

Comment: How would that look (I don't even know where to start in ActiveRecord with a sub-query). The criteria is: select the most recent project, e.g. highest value for `projects.finish_date`.

Comment: Thx for taking the time to explain. I actually understand the issue now and can think of a few ways to solve in our code base. That sub query is some arcane magic though, very impressive (and it does work ;).

Comment: Glad to hear it. I wrote the SQL and the ActiveRecord query using two tables I have locally, `users` and `photos`, and then translated the table and column names back to yours, so I was about 50% sure it would work as written.